# Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:

Tags: android, android-proguard

I made a mistake after proguard the code, please help me.
This is my error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
at b.b.c.o.run(ScheduledAction.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected 'long b.b.a.b.am.a' to be a static field rather than a instance field (declaration of 'b.b.a.b.ae' appears in /data/app/com.cfdaic.app-1/base.apk)
at b.b.a.b.ae.a(SpscArrayQueue.java:177)
at b.b.a.b.ae.offer(SpscArrayQueue.java:119)
at b.b.d.qs.c(OperatorObserveOn.java:159)
at b.b.d.mt.b(OnSubscribeTimerOnce.java:49)
at b.b.c.ag.b(EventLoopsScheduler.java:189)
at b.b.c.o.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
... 7 more
```

Comment: please post it as code, not image.And also post dependencies.

Comment: @ChrongLiu you should edit your question to include the code - not add it as a comment :)

Comment: My English is not very good，so description is not clear.I'll find other ways，Thanks.